# WFS-T Namespace

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

I've faced with this problem: The WFS POST request that OpenLayers
performs does not contains following namespaces:

```
xmlns:wfs="hxxp://www.opengis.net/wfs"
xmlns:ogc="hxxp://www.opengis.net/ogc"
xmlns:gml="hxxp://www.opengis.net/gml"
xmlns:xsi="hxxp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

The weird thing is that these namespaces are mentioned in test
expected value at OpenLayers\tests\Format\WFST\v1_1_0.html

...
<!--

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" resultType="hits"
xmlns:topp="hxxp://www.openplans.org/topp"
               xmlns:wfs="hxxp://www.opengis.net/wfs"
               xmlns:ogc="hxxp://www.opengis.net/ogc"
               xmlns:xsi="hxxp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="hxxp://www.opengis.net/wfs
hxxp://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
   <wfs:Query xmlns:wfs="hxxp://www.opengis.net/wfs"
typeName="topp:states" xmlns:topp="hxxp://www.openplans.org/topp">
       <wfs:PropertyName>STATE_NAME</wfs:PropertyName>
       <wfs:PropertyName>STATE_FIPS</wfs:PropertyName>
       <wfs:PropertyName>STATE_ABBR</wfs:PropertyName>
   </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

-->
...

I have analysed this test with FireBug and get following:

expected value (exp) is:

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" resultType="hits"
xmlns:topp="hxxp://www.openplans.org/topp"
               xmlns:wfs="hxxp://www.opengis.net/wfs"
               xmlns:ogc="hxxp://www.opengis.net/ogc"
               xmlns:xsi="hxxp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="hxxp://www.opengis.net/wfs
hxxp://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
   <wfs:Query xmlns:wfs="hxxp://www.opengis.net/wfs"
typeName="topp:states" xmlns:topp="hxxp://www.openplans.org/topp">
       <wfs:PropertyName>STATE_NAME</wfs:PropertyName>
       <wfs:PropertyName>STATE_FIPS</wfs:PropertyName>
       <wfs:PropertyName>STATE_ABBR</wfs:PropertyName>
   </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

And real value (got) is:

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" resultType="hits"
xsi:schemaLocation="hxxp://www.opengis.net/wfs
hxxp://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
   <wfs:Query xmlns:wfs="hxxp://www.opengis.net/wfs"
typeName="topp:states" xmlns:topp="hxxp://www.openplans.org/topp">
       <wfs:PropertyName>STATE_NAME</wfs:PropertyName>
       <wfs:PropertyName>STATE_FIPS</wfs:PropertyName>
       <wfs:PropertyName>STATE_ABBR</wfs:PropertyName>
   </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

As you can see there is no topp, wfs, ogc, xsi namespaces but test is
resulted as PASSED.

The fact that mentioned namespaces are missed caused following problem with the GeoServer:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport version="1.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="hxxp://www.opengis.net/ows
hxxp://services.local:80/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
 <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
  <ows:ExceptionText>
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: could not determine
namespace bound to element prefix wfs (position: START_DOCUMENT seen
...www.opengis.net/wfs
hxxp://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd&quot;&gt;... @1:139)
    could not determine namespace bound to element prefix wfs
(position: START_DOCUMENT seen ...www.opengis.net/wfs
hxxp://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd&quot;&gt;... @1:139)
  </ows:ExceptionText>
 </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

I have reported this issue on the GeoServer users mail list but no response yet.

Please if anybody have any idea on this issue help me. I've search all the internet with no luck. Maybe I've missed something?

Comment: Please, use *code blocks* and *quotes* to format your message

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

http://gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver/www/wfs/index.html to see how I've been using WFS layers in OpenLayers - there seems to be no problem in these requests. Without seeing the actual code you are using it's hard to say what is up.